# how to read characters from a string for android

Tags: android

how can i read characters from a string variable until a special character has reached, for example a '/'.it should be read from begining.
and how to send this string to another activity from onItemClickListener() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about split?

```
String theSeparator = "/";
String original = "Some string with a special char / and some content after the /";
String myString = original.split(Pattern.Quote(theSeparator))[0];
```

Now, passing the string when you start a new activity is pretty simple:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("My Super Special String", myString);
startActivity(i);
```

In the next activity, you call:

```
String myStringFromPreviousActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("My Super Special String");
```

Comment: yes i meant sending it to another activity with this string in its bundle

Comment: Did you find an answer already, or do you want me to give an example?

Comment: i did not get the complete solution,if u dont mind can u give me an example of this.

Comment: thank u for your help, and how can i read the String on which i have clicked

Comment: Add an `OnClickListener` and use the method `getText()`... There are plenty of questions like this in SO, and I don't want to spam the site with unrelated answers or extra comments. If you don't find a solution, please post another question in SO.

Comment: great job fellaw.

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString = "Send this String Out/Leave this one behind";
String toSendOut = "";
for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
    if(myString.charAt(i) != '/'){
        toSendOut = toSendOut + myString.charAt(i); 
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

`myString` is your inputted String, `toSendOut` is the string you're sending to wherever you want to send it to.

So, in this example, `toSendOut` will read "Send this String Out".  The way it does this is by checking one letter at a time in `myString`.  If the letter isn't "/", it adds that character to `toSendOut`.  The process loops until a "/" is hit, in which case the loop breaks (ends).

Answer (score 0):

```
            String s = "aaaaa/bbbbb";
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if(s.charAt(i) == '/'){
                    //Do whatever you like.
                }
            }
```

Take a look at the [javadocs for the String class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you will find lots of useful methods for interacting with and manipulating Strings.